# Populating array with new objects inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill an array with new objects, but the only thing I get is - **Uncaught TypeError: product is not a constructor**

Here's my code for obj. constructor:

```
function product(id, preview, colors, sizes, title, price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.preview = preview;
    this.colors = colors;
    this.sizes = sizes;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
};
```

and code for loop:

```
    var products = [];
    for( i=0; i<db.length; i++) {
        var xyz = db[i];
        products[i] = new product( xyz.id, xyz.preview, xyz.colors, xyz.sizes, xyz.title, xyz.price );
    };
```

here's "minfied" code block example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cujrfhyL/1/

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a minimal verifiable complete example?

Comment: Please provide a snippet that reproduces the issue so it would be easier to help you.

Comment: actually in the editted code, you should use `new product()` ;) Except for the fact that product6566 and product6646 could throw syntaxerror as they are undefined, but I am guessing that is a typo

Comment: Just've made a jsfiddle example.

Comment: And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tq1pmf7z/) you see it works

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/j40parjq/ Just add `new` when creating a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If products array variable already has some kind of data, it's better you use the array push as not to override the data it contains

```js
var product1 = { id: 6566, price: 3 };
var product2 = { id: 6566, price: 3 };  
var product3 = { id: 6568, price: 3 }; 

var db = [ product1, product2 ];

function product(id, price) {
 this.id = id;
 this.price = price;
};

var products = [new product(product3.id,product3.price)];

function addProducts() {
 for( i=0; i<db.length; i++) {
  var xyz = db[i];
  products.push(new product( xyz.id, xyz.price ));
 }
  console.log(products)
};

addProducts();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `new` operator.

`products[i] = new product( xyz.id, xyz.price );`

```js
var product1 = { id: 6566, price: 3 };
var product2 = { id: 6566, price: 3 };  

var db = [ product1, product2 ];

function product(id, price) {
 this.id = id;
 this.price = price;
};

var products = [];

function addProducts() {
 for( i=0; i<db.length; i++) {
  var xyz = db[i];
  products[i] = new product( xyz.id, xyz.price );
  alert(products[i]);
 }
};

addProducts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are having your same problem on local, but in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cujrfhyL/1/) you misstyped:

Written there:

```
var product1 = { id: 6566, price: 3 };
var product2 = { id: 6566, price: 3 };  
var db = [ product6566, product6646 ];
```

But you need to reference product1 and product2 in db:

```
var db = [ product1, product2 ];
```

Appart from that, you need to use the "new" keyword:

your code:

```
products[i] = product( xyz.id, xyz.price );
```

Correct code:

```
products[i] = new product( xyz.id, xyz.price );
```

In [Updated working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cujrfhyL/5/) you can see it working perfectly